# Copying default puredyne audio settings?

Tags: configuration, sound, jack

I would like to use Ubuntu as my main operating system but I get too many xruns when I run jack. I tried several solutions I found online but I could not solve the problem.
I am very happy with the audio settings in puredyne. Is there a way to compare audio settings in puredyne with the settings in ubuntu? which configuration files should I look into?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the only options for JACK are passed from command-line, when the daemon is started. The only config file I know is ~/.jackdrc (i guess it is used by qjackctl) which stores the command that is used to run JACK, with all the arguments. So for example my ~/.jackdrc contains:

```
/usr/bin/jackd -P5 -m -dalsa -dplughw:0 -r44100 -p1024 -n3 -o4
```

It does store full config. So if you want to copy the configuration from puredyne, have a look into this file.